# Recieve Bluetooth Audio Signal as Microphone Input for SpeechRecognizer

Tags: android-studio, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, android-bluetooth, microphone

I am using a Raspberry Pi to take a microphone input and filter background noise using a pretrained ML model. I would like to stream the filtered audio  to an Android Device and use SpeechRecognizer in Android Studio to transcribe the text. However, from what I've seen in the docs, RecognizerIntent is the only interface for the SpeechRecognizer, which only sources directly from the microphone. Is there any way I can receive the Bluetooth audio as a microphone input so that it can be fed to the SpeechRecognizer?